# sending the args to a java program using the wildcard

Tags: java, wildcard

Is there a way to call a Java program and pass the args using the wildcard and expect the program to run the code on all the files that match the wildcard pattern:

```
  java -jar code.jar ~/folder/ma-*/*/en-*.txt
```

So, I expect this to run this program on everything that matches the pattern. i.e:

```
  java -jar code.jar ~/folder/ma-1/aaa/en-434x.txt
  java -jar code.jar ~/folder/ma-xa/b1001a/en-321312.txt
  java -jar code.jar ~/folder/ma-22x1/cxz/en-22.txt
```

Comment: Yes there is a way: code the program accordingly. You'd still have one call and the programm would then interpret the wildcards, list the files and operate on them.

Comment: The shell can expand the wildcard so the program sees multiple arguments.

Comment: @stark I tried the script, but it stops after the first match: #!/bin/bash
args=("$@")
java -jar dist/TestConvertor.jar ${args[0]} ${args[1]}

Answer (score 0):

Normally the shell does this for you. Important to know is that Netbeans will not do this when you add the wildcard as a parameter in the run configuration.

Anyway, you can also do it pragmatically:

```
final Path dir = Paths.get("~/folder");
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "ma-*/*/en-*.txt")) {
    for (Path entry : stream) {
        System.out.println(entry.getFileName());
    }
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

Beware that only the system shell is able to resolve the `~` to the home dir path.

Comment: But this requires hardcoding folder and the pattern in the code.

Comment: You can get them from the `args[]` parameter in your main class. If they are passed in one piece (like `~/folder/ma-*/*/en-*.txt`) then you need to seperate out the base folder for the `dir` variable.